# SQL Many2Many (Association Table) as read only with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, cascade

I'm working on a web-service using `spring rest` and I use `spring data jpa` to persist my models. In this example, i will implement simple users that can have multiples activities (represented by an association table in database).

Having the following models:

> SQL TABLES

```
> user_detail <
id (int)

> activity <
id (int)

> user_activity <
user_id (int) | activity_id (int)
```

> JAVA

```
@Entity
@table(name = "user_detail")
@Getter @Setter
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_activity",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "activity_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Activity> activities;
}

@Entity
@Getter @Setter
public class Activity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "activities", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<User> users;
}
```

Each entity has its own `crud repository` implemented at the compilation time by spring data (by code generation)

```
@Repository
public interface ActivityRepository extends CrudRepository<Activity, Integer> {}

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {}
```

With all of this, now I am able to `get` (one or all), `create`, `update` or `delete` an activity and user. The code above works fine but I have a problem about cascaded operations.

Given the following [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html#cascade()), `@ManyToMany` is supposed to have no cascaded operation, since the following citation

> Defaults to no operations being cascaded.

However, if I load `1 user` with `1 activity`, and then `remove` this activity from the `Set<Activity>`, on saving, it gonna remove the link between the user and the activity in the association table. It does make no sens. There should be no effect since there is no defined cascaded operations.
**What's wrong?**

**EDIT:** The deal of this topic is to find a way to make the `Set<Activity>` provided by `@ManyToMany` and `@Jointable` as `read-only`. The closest approach I found is `updatable=false` from `@JoinColumn` but not possible in my case.

I also tried the code below:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable=false),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "activity_id", `referencedColumnName = "id", updatable=false))
private Set<Activity> activities;
```

It didn't solved the problem.

**EDIT:** Maybe isn't this possible? Maybe should I create a specific method into the repository that return activities of a given user?

Comment: What about simply preventing modification of the Collection? `private Set<Activity> activities getActivities(){ return Collections.unmodifiableSet(Activities) };`

Comment: Models are loaded, then serialized as json and pushed to the front-end. The front can update the data and then put in on the webservice (via http method PUT). So my webservice deserialize the json into the Model and saves it. It's not possible to prevent modifications in your way.

Comment: seems that nobody knows.

Comment: up .............

Comment: What about @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY) which should prevent deserialization.

Comment: another up, any idea?